# How prove this inequality $|x|+|y|+|z|\ge 2$ with $xy+yz+xz=-1$

Tags: inequality

**Question:**

> let $x,y,z\in \mathbb{R}$  such that $$xy+yz+xz+1=0$$
>
> show that:
> $$|x|+|y|+|z|\ge 2$$

I know
$$(|x|+|y|+|z|)^2\ge 3(|xy|+|yz|+|xz|)\ge 3(xy+yz+xz)$$

But this relust is not usefull,so How prove this ineuqlity?Thank you

Comment: @AngeloRendina Did I miss the assumption that $xyz=1$ somewhere? That for is not correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use $$\begin{align*}(|x|+|y|+|z|)^2&=(x+y+z)^2-2(xy+yz+zx)+2(|xy|+|yz|+|zx|)\\&\geqslant0+2+2(|xy|+|yz|+|zx|)\\&\geqslant2+2|xy+yz+zx|\\&=4.\end{align*}$$
Some intuition: since we expect equality for $(x,y,z)=(1,-1,0)$ and permutations, it's a good idea to try to use $(x+y+z)^2\geqslant0$ somewhere.